# Not able to download valid zip file using angularjs, however on directly hitting my rest api it is working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is my **angular.js** code

```
App.factory('JobMigrationService', ['$http','$q',function($http, $q) {

return {
    downloadSvc: function(requestPayload) {
        console.info(requestPayload);
        return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/XXXX',{params:{"params":value}},{responseType:'arraybuffer'})
        .then(
                function(response){
                    console.info(response);
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    var blob = new Blob([success], {'type':"application/octet-stream",'responseType':"arraybuffer"});
                    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    a.download = "filename.zip";
                    a.click();
                }, 
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error');
                    return $q.reject(errResponse);
                }
        );
    }
}

}]);
```

Download is happening but when try to open the zip file it says it is invalid however using the rest api direct hit it is working fine.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this must be it

```
  var blob = new Blob([success], {'type':"application/octet-stream",'responseType':"arraybuffer"});
```

Whats [success] ? shouldnt it be

```
   var blob = new Blob(response.data, {'type':"application/octet-stream",'responseType':"arraybuffer"});
```

This is a bit cleaner. I think

```
    App.factory('JobMigrationService', ['$http','$q',function($http, $q) {

return {
    downloadSvc: function(requestPayload) {
        console.info(requestPayload);
        return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/XXXX',{params:{"params":value}},{responseType:'blob'})
        .then(
                function(response){
                    console.info(response);
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
                    a.download = "filename.zip";
                    a.click();
                }, 
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error');
                    return $q.reject(errResponse);
                }
        );
    }
}

}]);
```